# react app crashes on refresh [webpack , REACT ]

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

so I have this react webpack project I'm running using `webpack-dev-server`  everything works fine , but when the url is two layers deep  and I refresh the page the app crashes .

for example if I was at `http://localhost:8080/product/someProductId`
or `http://localhost:8080/checkout/information`
I get this error when I refresh `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` 

but if its `http://localhost:8080/shop` it wont crash on refresh

here is my webpack config  :

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports ={
    entry :"./src/index.js",
    devServer:{historyApiFallback: true},
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,"./dist"),
        filename:'index.js',
    },
    plugins:[
        new HTMLPlugin({template:'./src/index.html'}),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
              { from: './src/images', to: 'images' },
            ],
          }),
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            { 
                test : /\.js$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader:"babel-loader"
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/,
                include: [
                  path.join(__dirname, './src/images')
                ],
                loader: 'file-loader',
             },
            {
                test:/.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)$/, 
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                      limit: 100000000,
                    }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: ['source-map-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json's scripts :

```
 "scripts": {
    "nodemon": "nodemon ./backEnd/app.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot -inline --progress --content-base ",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --progress"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell Webpack Dev Server to redirect all server requests to `/index.html`. There are just two properties in your webpack config you need to set to do this, `publicPath` and `historyApiFallback`.

```
publicPath: '/',
historyApiFallback: true,
```

`publicPath` allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application. `historyAPIFallback` will redirect 404s to /index.html.

Here’s an example :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
// rest of your config ...
};
```

more details check [this](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/)